# write review on tripadvisor with script

Tags: java, python, api, bots, tripadvisor

is possible write a script to make review on tripadvisor without enter in the site. Maybe with python, java or similar. Exist some API to use or similar? I have found nothing on the internet
Thank you!

Comment: I can't comment on the feasibility here, but would like to say that this feels like a mildly unethical thing to do

Comment: yes i know, i want only try for myself, it not will be used

Comment: Alright, fair enough

Answer (score 0):

I found an [API](https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/) but you will have to ask for an [access key](https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/request-api-access/):

> Tripadvisor grants only a limited number of API keys, and does not
> allow access to the Content API for purposes of:
>
> - Data analysis
> - Academic research
> - Any use not associated with a consumer-facing (B2C) travel website or application